# C passing char array to a function and pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, chararray

So, I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around using arrays and pointers in functions.
I want to print the following array of chars using a function. I can print them outside the function with the for loop but when I pass the same code to the function, the function returns NULLS. Could I get some insight on this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printNames(char arr[], int size);

int main()
{
    
    char *names[4] = {"Bruce", "Clark", "Barry", "Diana"};

    //changed a typo
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", *(names + i));
    }

    printNames(names, 4);

    return 0;


}

void printNames(char arr[], int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", *(arr + i));
    }


}
```

Comment: `names` is an array of four pointers to `char`, i.e. `char *[4]`. The `printNames` argument `arr` is a pointer to `char`, i.e. `char *`.

Comment: Also remember (or learn) that for any pointer or array `arr` and index `i`, the expression `*(arr + i)` is *exactly* equal to `arr[i]`. The latter (`arr[i]`) is not only easier to read and understand, but also less to write.

Comment: Also, `for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)`? That will make you print 15 elements of the four-element array... And lead to *undefined behavior* as you go out of bounds.

Comment: Lastly, you initialize `names` using only *one* string, all the remaining three elements will be null pointers. Which you dereference and again have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: You cannot pass an array to a function in C (unless you wrap it in a struct).  You can only pass a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings as `void printNames(char arr[], int size); char *names[4] = ... printNames(names, 4);` is a problem.  Faster feedback than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a variable of type `char *[]`, i.e. an array of pointers to `char` to a function expecting `char *`, i.e. a pointer to char.  Also, inside of `printNames`, you're passing a single `char` to `printf` when the `%s` format specifier expects a `char *`.  Your compiler should have warned you about both of these.

You need to change the definition of `printNames` to have the parameter type match what is passed in and to match what you want to pass to `printf`.

```
void printNames(char *arr[], int size);
```